# How to overlay an image over embedded video?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, google-drive-api

I'm looking put put some text over google drive embedded player (using iframe)

CSS & HTML:

```css
#over {

  position: absolute;

  top: 0px;

  left: 0px;

  background-color: #FF0000;

  height: 30px;

}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="over">This is Preview</div>
  <iframe src="https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B5GSymfNadlIV1NJRFpITWJLNHc/preview" width="640" height="480"></iframe>
</div>
```

But the text is not overlaying the video player on my site. I'm working on wordpress mh-joylite theme. Please suggest me, point my mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your video iframe and floating text and make the parent `position: relative`, like so:

```css
.video {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  
  /* ie7 inline-block support */
  *display: inline;
  *zoom: 1;
}

#over {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<div class="video">
  <div id="over">This is Preview</div>
  <iframe src="https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B5GSymfNadlIV1NJRFpITWJLNHc/preview" width="640" height="480"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Still not working. Text is displayed above the video.

Comment: I'm confused, is the text not overlaying the video in your page? or in the demo? Ported the demo to jsbin for a better view, http://output.jsbin.com/yebayuvudi

Comment: Is your video and overlay text wrapped in a div with the `position: relative` property? Do you have a link to the page so I can take a look?

Comment: It is in the div with `position: relative`...But I'm working on my localhost. I can't provide any link. I can make a screenshot though.

Comment: Please do, also of your code, that way i can spot whats missing. If the wrapping container already has the `position: relative` property then the overlay text should use that as its boundary point. Unless you have negative positioning values such as `top`, `left`, `bottom` or `right`, or simply a negative margin somewhere.